# My TFS agent is not working automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, build, azure-devops

My TFS agent is working fine on the first build but after completion of this build, the agent needs Ctrl+C to be typed in run.cmd, I want is automatic not manual interaction, how?

Comment: Hi, can you please go into some more detail here? Is there any build or build definition configuration information you can provide?

Comment: when i start agent cmd.exe for starting agent to start build, first build run successfully then the next trigger build does not run automatically, we have to restart the cmd.exe for it.. but i want to run it automatically thank u

Comment: Another thread issue is related to trigger build task, what's the result if you just run the empty builds?

Answer (score 1):

Which kind of problem do you have? Next build can not be started (or any another)? You may configure your build agent to start as service also:
[image]

Comment: Authentication with TFS Server failed. Please check your settings. This is the error coming on next build trigger

Comment: Do you use PAT? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts

Comment: @AbidAli if you use username/password so when you enter the username you need also the domain (domain\username).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you build agent **configured as service mode** not  interactive mode.

If you configured the agent to run as a service, it starts automatically. You can view and control the agent running status from the services snap-in. Run **services.msc** and look for "VSTS Agent (name of your agent)".

As your described, sounds like the root cause is your build agent not configured properly. For the second failed build, suggest you remote to your build agent server and try to run the build use command line to narrow down if the issue related to TFS or environment.

Also suggest you to [reconfigure your build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts#remove-and-re-configure-an-agent) or deployed a totally new build agent, then test again.